# set likes based on 2 parameters

Tags: ruby, sinatra-activerecord

I'm working on a project which should be able to put likes on it... one from each user that log into the page. I'm using ruby, active record and sinatra.

```
post '/like/:isbn' do
   if favourite = Favourite.find_by(book_id: params[:book_id])
    redirect to "/info/#{ params[:isbn] }"
else
  favourite = Favourite.new
  favourite.book_id = params[:book_id]
  favourite.user_id = current_user.id
  favourite.save
  redirect to "/info/#{ params[:isbn] }"
end
```

end
what I'm trying to do is searching for this favourite `where my book_id = book_id && user_id = user_id`... but I can't think of a way of putting it into ruby code....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you try this

```
Favourite.where(:my_book_id=> book_id , :user_id=> user_id)
```

this will return the array of favourite which has both `:my_boo_id = book_id` and `:user_id = user_id`

Comment: I checked again with other users but it doesn't work

Comment: what do u mean by other users. please explain in details.

Comment: if I log into my web app with other users .. so I wanna make that like unique from a certain user to a certain book... but allow other users to like the same book...